# Why is B flat in this key sigiture when B is never played?

Tags: sheet-music, key-signatures

In the below sheet music B is marked as flat however the only notes played are `g g g d e c C`. Is that just a typo on the part of the person who made this image and it should be on the upper C or am I missing something else?

[image: staff]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sharps and flats in the key signature are one indication as to the key of a piece. Lacking those notes in the actual music is irrelevant. For example, play all the white notes on a keyboard in order from C to the next C an octave higher. Now do the same from F to F. Hear how it sounds weird on the 4th note (B)? That's because you need to play it in the key of F. Now try playing F to F again but this time play Bb instead of B.

Comment: It also tells accompanists to use chords that do not contain B natural.

Comment: @neilfein I think that's true only for simplistic music. Music that an accompanist would play (songs, for example) modulate. A common modulation is to 5 of 5, which has a raised 4th. In this case, that's to G, which uses B natural.

Comment: Speaking as a working musician who uses notation for traditional folk tunes: Your jab at "simplistic" music aside, modulations away from the basic key *should* be noted in the notation, either in this staff or other staves in the same work. (If they're not, someone did an incomplete job of transcription.)